# Как получить последовательность вызова метода из Log?

Tags: java, android

Нужно собрать класс который будет отправлять логи на север. Есть у меня вот такой метод который возвращает название класса, название метода и строку в которой произошла ошибка.

```
private static String getLocation() {
    final String className = Logger.class.getName();
    final StackTraceElement[] traces = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    boolean found = false;

    for (StackTraceElement trace : traces) {
        try {
            if (found) {
                if (!trace.getClassName().startsWith(className)) {
                    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(trace.getClassName());
                    return "[" + getClassName(clazz) + ":" + trace.getMethodName() + ":" + trace.getLineNumber() + "]: ";
                }
            } else if (trace.getClassName().startsWith(className)) {
                found = true;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }

    return "[]: ";
}

private static String getClassName(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (clazz != null) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(clazz.getSimpleName())) {
            return clazz.getSimpleName();
        }
        return getClassName(clazz.getEnclosingClass());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Но мне помимо этой информации нужно еще знать от куда изначально был вызван метод который дал ошибку

Когда я передаю в `Log` `Throwable e` то он отлично распечатывает все что нужно и ошибку и причину и последовательность вызова до метода где ошибка произошла

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method  'java.lang.Object org.json.JSONObject.get(java.lang.String)' on a null   object reference
at  com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.TestDeleteIt.fff(TestDeleteIt.java:45)
at  com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.TestDeleteIt.testImagesd(TestDeleteIt.java:35)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at  android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onCli ck(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java :1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

но когда я беру `Throwable e` и вызываю `e.toString();` то я получаю только причину ошибки...

Как получить последовательность вызова?

**ПРАВКА**

Вот что возвращает метод `getStackTrace()`

```
com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.wrappers.Logger.getLocation(Logger.java:26)
com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.wrappers.Logger.logError(Logger.java:21)
com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.TestDeleteIt.fff(TestDeleteIt.java:47)
```

Он показывает что ошибка возникла в строке 47 и далее уже показывает логи класса логирования... Вот все дело в том, что строка 47 это место возникновения ошибки, но что вызвало этот метод в 47 строке которого произошла ошибка он не показывает...

А вот распечатка `Throwable e` в самом логе

```
Log.e("TAG", message, e);
```

это показывает

вот

```
at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.TestDeleteIt.fff(TestDeleteIt.java:45)
at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.TestDeleteIt.testImagesd(TestDeleteIt.java:35)
```

тут видно что ошибка возникла в строке 35 изначально и уже в 45 строке она была перехвачена...

```
public void testImagesd(View view) {
    fff();  <--- строка 35
}

private void fff(){
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject.get("");    <---- строка 45
    } catch (JSONException | NullPointerException e) {
        Logger.logError("jsonObject : null --- " + e, e);  <--- строка 47
    }
}
```

Как взять этот стактрейс??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классе `java.lang.Throwable` есть метод `public StackTraceElement[] getStackTrace()`. Из возвращенного массива можно получить список классов и методов вызываемых до возникновения исключения.

Comment: Обратите внимание что я использую этот метод в вопросе, но он возвращает мне не последовательность от места вызова до возникновения ошибки, а от места возникновения и до метода который логирует это ... то есть история начинает записываться от возникновения ошибки а не от метода который справоцировал ее с самого начала

Comment: Я считаю что это не является ответом, причину описал в дополнение к вопросу

Comment: Я считаю, что вы не правильно используете метод. Попробуйте вот этот код.     public static void main(String[] args){
        method();
    }


    private static void method() {
        try {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hello world");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            show(e);
        }
    }

    public static void show(Throwable e) {
        for(StackTraceElement element: e.getStackTrace())
            System.out.println(element);
    }  Будет выведен стектрейс именно до метода `method`